# Making a .bmp file have some transparency

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I am making an android 2d game and ran into a problem. I made a .bmp file with transparency in paint.net and exported it to eclipse.  It is the cross hare that should be transparent in the center so that you see where your character is going.  Unless I exported it incorrectly, i was unable to make my game have some transparency in it, in the correct areas.

Here is the code I added

```
...
  Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
...
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;

  Resources res = context.getResources();
  crosshair = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.crosshare,options);
....
  c.drawBitmap(crosshair, x, y, paint);
```

c  is the canvas and the first 5 lines of code are in the constructor of my crosshare class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your `bmp` file into `png` should solve your problem. Not only do `png` files have natural support for transparency, they are also smaller than `bmp` files.

Oh, and `png` is an open format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the paint alpha? paint.setAlpha(100);... Also if that doesn't work, which I dont think it does on bitmaps, try using a BitmapDrawable(Resource res). This will allow you to call setAlpha() directly on the Drawable. You shouldnt have to change much to use this.